# Importing package with classes that inherits the base class

Tags: python, inheritance, import

I have a question about importing packages that consist of classes that inherits a base class. Here is my directory structure:

```
.
|-- cisco.py
|-- cisco.pyc
|-- __init__.py
|-- __init__.pyc
|-- objects.py
`-- objects.pyc

0 directories, 6 files
user@jumpbox:~/objects#
```

My parent class is inside of objects.py:

```
class BasePlatform(object):
        def __init__(self,ip,hostname):
                self.ip = ip
                self.hostname = hostname

                print self.ip,self.hostname

        def hello(self):
                print 'hello world'
```

And my child class is inside of cisco.py:

```
class CiscoPlatform(BasePlatform):
        def somefunc(self):
                print 'hello world'
```

Inside of my **init**.py, I have this:

```
from . import objects 
from . import cisco
```

But when I execute, this is the error I get:

```
user@jumpbox:~/objects# cd ..
user@jumpbox:~# python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "objects/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import cisco
  File "objects/cisco.py", line 1, in <module>
    class CiscoPlatform(BasePlatform):
NameError: name 'BasePlatform' is not defined
>>>
```

May someone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
from objects import BasePlatform
class CiscoPlatform(BasePlatform):
     def somefunc(self):
         print 'hello world'
```

You need to import the `BasePlatform` class to cisco.py